# Why does OpenWrap cause my projects to fail with a "InitializeVisualStudioIntegration" compilation error?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, openrasta, openwrap

Suddenly I cannot compile the following openrasta projects (see errors at end):

- OpenRasta.Codecs.WebForms
- OpenRasta.Hosting.AspNet

This has happened after I did two things:

1. I installed the latest version of OpenWrap from the wiki. This is the first time I have installed openwrap. I did nothing else, just ran the installer. No messing around.
2. Pulled the latest versions of the following projects from GitHub:

   - OpenRasta.Core
   - OpenRasta.Codecs.WebForms
   - OpenRasta.Hosting.AspNet

I then attempted a rebuild of my main project, which includes project references to the OR projects above. This gave me the "InitializeVisualStudioIntegration" errors (see end).

I found one mention of this problem online (http://tinyurl.com/3d8oxsf), something to do with nesting levels of the project files so FYI my OR projects all live at the following levels of nesting:

F:\Development\OpenRasta\openrasta-codecs-webforms\src\OpenRasta.Codecs.WebForms\OpenRasta.Codecs.WebForms.csproj

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Jonny

### Errors

The "WrapDescriptor" parameter is not supported by the "InitializeVisualStudioIntegration" task. Verify the parameter exists on the task, and it is a settable public instance property.    OpenRasta.Codecs.WebForms

The "InitializeVisualStudioIntegration" task could not be initialized with its input parameters.

The "WrapDescriptor" parameter is not supported by the "InitializeVisualStudioIntegration" task. Verify the parameter exists on the task, and it is a settable public instance property.    OpenRasta.Hosting.AspNet

The "InitializeVisualStudioIntegration" task could not be initialized with its input parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had one user with that problem before and we never managed to find out what was going on, somehow the msbuild tasks and openwrap dlls got out of sync, which was indeed very strange.

Can you make sure you have the shell version 2.0.0.10 shell? If all fails, delete the content of /wraps and do an update-wrap that'd get a clean copy